Clone of SSD does not boot on new PC
I have used the tool "Samsung Data Migration" (v.3.1) to clone my 500 GB Samsung SSD with one 199 GB Windows 10 partition (next to two ~550MB Partitions) to another similar Samsung SSD (exact same product).
The result on the target SSD is a 524MB Partition next to a 500GB Partition. The second ~550MB partition was ignored by the tool.
Oiginal SSD:

Target SSD ("Clone"):

After that I have put the clone SSD into a brandnew PC to se if it is usable. The SSD is recognized correctly in the Gigabyte BIOS but at the same time it's stated there, that no bootable device is found. All I get get into is BIOS, nothing else.
What mistake did I make here?

@Magier No worries. It's notable that the EFI partition should be formatted as FAT12/FAT16/FAT32 (actually not quite, the UEFI standard specifies a fs based on FAT but it's slightly different... though actual FAT32 filesystems are usually supported). Here it seems to be indicating that the filesystem is NTFS... which is not supported for EFI partitions afaik. Not quite sure what to make of that, especially given that the original system is still working. The missing Partition 3 on the new drive is also something to look in to.

@CliffArmstrong - the disk is MBR - so, is EFI even relevant?

@Bravo - Absolutely. It also means there isn’t an EFi partition. It appears Cliff did not properly diagnose the problem.

@Ramhound - that is what I was trying to say, is the format of the non-existent EFI Partition relevant

If it's MBR then no, efi isn't relevant. I missed that detail. Although that is, again, extremely unusual for a modern Windows installation.
